# Typescript: Partial<this> as parameter type not work

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to make the following code compile, but it fails in `C.inc` method  with message:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ counter: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<this>'.
```

The Code fails to compile:

```
class B {
    clone(diff: Partial<this>): this {
        return this; // omit the implementation.
    }
}

class C extends B {
    counter = 0;
    inc() {
        return this.clone({
            counter: this.counter + 1
        })
    }
}
```

But the following code can compile (without the `C.inc` method):

```
let c = new C();
c.clone({ counter: c.counter + 1 });
```

I want to know why.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why `Partial<this>` doesn't work, but [`Pick` works](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20clone%3CK%20extends%20keyof%20this%3E(diff%3A%20Pick%3Cthis%2C%20K%3E)%3A%20this%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%3B%20%2F%2F%20omit%20the%20implementation.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20C%20extends%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20counter%20%3D%200%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20inc()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this.clone(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20counter%3A%20this.counter%20%2B%201%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D):

```
class B {
    clone<K extends keyof this>(diff: Pick<this, K>): this {
        return this; // omit the implementation.
    }
}

class C extends B {
    counter = 0;
    inc() {
        return this.clone({
            counter: this.counter + 1
        })
    }
}
```

I would love to know the reason!